# locate any bifurcation in the $2D$ system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

bifurcation for the following $2D$ system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x′=ux-y+x^3\\ 
y'=bx-y
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have got $ux-y+x^3=0,\ y=bx$, then $x=0\ \ \text{and}\ x = \pm \sqrt{b-u}$.

But I don't how to continue to find the bifurcation?

Comment: what is the stability of the critical point?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, for $b<u$ there is only one stationary point at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. The Jacobian at this point is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
u&-1\\b&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
with eigenvalues given by 
$$0=z^2-(u-1)z+(b-u)=(z-\tfrac12(u-1))^2-(\tfrac14(u-1)^2-(b-u)).$$
When crossing the point $b=u$, the sign structure of the eigenvalues changes. But much also depends on the sign of $(u-1)$.

Comment: So the bifurcation is b=u=1?